# Convert month number to name in python pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I have a date column in pandas data frame I need to convert month number to name:

```
Date
01-01-2018, 
02-02-2018,
03-04-2018.
```

to

```
01-JAN-2018,
02-Feb-2018,
03-April-2018
```

Comment: repeated question: please refer
[Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625334/python-pandas-convert-month-int-to-month-name)

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python/pandas: convert month int to month name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625334/python-pandas-convert-month-int-to-month-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

[Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/) is a useful resource for constructing `datetime` string formats.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""Date
01-01-2018 
02-02-2018
03-04-2018""")

# if necessary, read data and convert to datetime
df = pd.read_csv(mystr)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

# apply string formatting
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

print(df)

          Date
0  01-Jan-2018
1  02-Feb-2018
2  03-Apr-2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by parsing the column as a datetime, and then modifying the string representation, before converting it back to a string:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

d = {"date": ["01-01-2018", "02-02-2018", "03-04-2018"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# %M = 01, %b = Jan, "%b".upper() = JAN
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%M-%Y"))
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, "%d-%b-%Y").upper())
```

```
print(df)

          date
0  01-JAN-2018
1  02-JAN-2018
2  03-JAN-2018
```