# How to run a script on x axis of plots in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

[image]

I the following graph which i had plotted with `matplotlib`. The X Axis has month and day over which it is plotted. Is there anyway possible to run a code which would convert the data to readable months like Jan Feb. Some way where the 1 to 12 would be converted through an iteration?

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625334/python-pandas-convert-month-int-to-month-name) but in this question the month was a column value, where in my case month is an index column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310169/8719679

Comment: The only part that matters is how to go from (month number 1-12) to "short month name".  The answers in the question Peter linked to give a number of different solutions, most of which *will* apply to your case.  Read 'em (again if need be).