# Wan to get group by date and status from the data

Tags: python

I have below data

```
data=[
{"name":"aa"..."created_at":"2022-01-17 07:38:26.403Z","status":"success"},
{"name":"bb"..."created_at":"2021-12-1 07:38:26.403Z","status":"failed"},
{"name":"kk"..."created_at":"2022-01-13 07:38:26.403Z","status":"success"},

{"name":"ll"..."created_at":"2021-12-17 07:38:26.403Z","status":"success"},

]
```

I want a report like

```
created_at,success

December,1
Jan,2
```

I tried below

```
 d = defaultdict(int)
 for i in kk:
     if(i["status"] == 'success')
     d[i["status"]]+=1
```

It give only success count but not able to do in month wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your 'created_at' column to datetime using `pd.to_datetime`, filter for your 'success' rows, and then use `groupby` per month with the aggregation of `count`:

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
out = df.loc[df.status.eq('success')].groupby(df.created_at.dt.month).status.count()
```

prints:

```
   created_at  success
0           1        2
1          12        1

# as a dict

>>> out.set_index('created_at').to_dict()
{'success': {1: 2, 12: 1}}
```

Then you can just convert the month numbers to month names as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625334/python-pandas-convert-month-int-to-month-name)

Comment: @Rajarshi DAs I believe that the  accepted answer make use of `pandas` library to do the analysis. So please tag your question appropriately in future to avoid any confusion. Currently it's tagged only under `python`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the date using `datetime.strptime` first, and use [`itetools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group based on month.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>>
>>> data = [
...     {"name": "aa", "created_at": "2022-01-17 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "success"},
...     {"name": "bb", "created_at": "2021-12-1 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "failed"},
...     {"name": "kk", "created_at": "2022-01-13 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "success"},
...     {"name": "ll", "created_at": "2021-12-17 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "success"},
... ]
>>>
>>>
>>> def custom_key_fun(row):
...     created_at_as_datetime = datetime.strptime(
...         row["created_at"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ"
...     )
...     month = calendar.month_abbr[created_at_as_datetime.month]
...     return month
...
>>>
>>> result = {
...     key: sum(1 for row in group if row["status"] == "success")
...     for key, group in groupby(sorted(data, key=custom_key_fun), key=custom_key_fun)
... }
>>>
>>> print(result)
{'Dec': 1, 'Jan': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = [{"name": "aa", "created_at": "2022-01-17 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "success"},
        {"name": "bb", "created_at": "2021-12-1 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "failed"},
        {"name": "kk", "created_at": "2022-01-13 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "success"},
        {"name": "ll", "created_at": "2021-12-17 07:38:26.403Z", "status": "success"},
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
    name    created_at  status
0   aa  2022-01-17 07:38:26.403Z    success
1   bb  2021-12-1 07:38:26.403Z     failed
2   kk  2022-01-13 07:38:26.403Z    success
3   ll  2021-12-17 07:38:26.403Z    success
```

Build new column

```
def date_convert(x):
    x = x.split('.')[0]
    return datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%B")


df['month_name'] = df.created_at.apply(date_convert)
df
    name    created_at  status  month_name
0   aa  2022-01-17 07:38:26.403Z    success     January
1   bb  2021-12-1 07:38:26.403Z     failed  December
2   kk  2022-01-13 07:38:26.403Z    success     January
3   ll  2021-12-17 07:38:26.403Z    success     December
```

Calculate & Build New DataFrame

```
group_month = df[df.status == "success"].groupby('month_name').groups
data = [{"created_at": i, "success": len(j)} for i, j in group_month.items()]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df
    created_at  success
0   December    1
1   January     2
```