# How to convert date into month name and day name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

This is the orginal date that I have in my dataset 01/04/2021 in the format day/month/year.
When I use **pandas time stamp** to convert the date to month name and day name it switches the format to m/d/y for the days <12 and uses it as it is for dates > 12.
For eg 01/04/2021 - month- January
13/04/2021 - month - April.

Code

```
for attacks in df['Create Date/Time']:
  event_date.append(pd.Timestamp(attacks).day)
  event_month.append(pd.Timestamp(attacks).month_name())
  event_year.append (pd.Timestamp(attacks).year)
  event_day.append(pd.Timestamp(attacks).day_name())
  combined_time.append(pd.Timestamp(attacks).ctime())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625334/python-pandas-convert-month-int-to-month-name

Comment: Don't loop, use `pandas.to_datetime` with `dayfirst=False` to convert the whole Series

Comment: I meant `dayfirst=True`...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to achieve what I think your question is asking (or something close):

```
import pandas as pd
records = [
    {'Create Date/Time': '01/04/2021'},
    {'Create Date/Time': '13/04/2021'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df)
ser = pd.to_datetime(df['Create Date/Time'], dayfirst=True)
print("date series:\n", ser)
ser = ser.apply(lambda dt:' '.join((dt.month_name(), dt.day_name())))
print("month name and day name series:\n", ser)
```

Output:

```
  Create Date/Time
0       01/04/2021
1       13/04/2021
date series:
 0   2021-04-01
1   2021-04-13
Name: Create Date/Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
month name and day name series:
 0    April Thursday
1     April Tuesday
Name: Create Date/Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: @GoodOldGuy Glad to hear my answer worked. Do you need any more help with your question?